# why this app is not working on PowerPC G4

Tags: cocoa, macos, architecture, powerpc

I am working on a mac app. My setup is as follows -

Xcode 3.2.5
Mac OS X 10.6.6

and here are the target properties -

[image]

My Client is using PowerBook G4 12'. Here is his configuration -

```
Model Name: PowerBook G4 12'Model Identifier: PowerBook 6,1Processor Name: PowerPC G4 (3.3)Processor Speed: 867 MHzNumber of CPUs: 1L2 cache (per cpu): 256 KBMemory: 1.12 GBBus Speed: 133 MHzBoot ROM version: 4.5.5faSerial number: UV3132DTMRTHardware UUID: 00000000-0000-80000-000A956CD1C6
```

I think for PowerPC G4 I should include the ppc7400 in the "valid architectures" but client is getting this following error -

[image]

My Question is what settings are needed to run this app on PowerPC G4?

**Edit 1 -**

**I -** yes it runs well on my machine.
**II -** Here is the output of file command on executable.
[image]
**III -** Yes I am on xcode 3.2.5
**iV -** client is only getting the error in popup.
V -  64 bit integer math is already disabled
[image]

Comment: help me obi wan kenobi, your my only hope!!

Comment: I can't think of any reason to use one of the processor-specific architectures (ppc7400 for G4, ppc970 for G5). Maybe if you have G5-specific assembly code for some reason, but otherwise, the only significant difference is that G5s support 64-bit, for which you can use ppc64.

Comment: but the app is not running on G4 ... I have build it as "32 bit Universal" but no luck.. any more ideas?

Comment: Saurabh: I think you misread my comment. I was addressing your suggestion that specifying ppc7400 instead of ppc would be a solution. It wouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

First, does it run on your machine? If you get the same error on an Intel Mac, that suggests that something else is the problem.

Second, run `file` on your executable and see what architectures it actually was built for. Edit that information into your question.

Third, make sure you really are running Xcode 3.2.5 and not 3.2.6. Xcode 3.2.6 removed PowerPC from the predefined architectures-list variables. If you've upgraded to 3.2.6, you will need to include ppc in your Architectures build setting by name.

Fourth, ask your client to send you any output about your app that appears in the Console application, and edit that into your question.

Fifth, [try turning off the “64-bit Integer Math” build setting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105924/how-do-i-build-universal-binaries-ppc-i386-using-xcode-3-2-2-for-osx/4409479#4409479).